# How to convert angular material datepicker date to UTC format?

Tags: angular

I'm taking date input and using angular material datepicker, and storing in a reactive-form variable.
But I want the date to be of UTC format, either by taking input in UTC or by taking input in any other format and converting it to UTC.
How do I do this.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="row" fxFlex="50%" class="pr-4">
    <mat-label>Invoice Date</mat-label>
    <input type='date' matInput name="" id="" formControlName="invoiceDate" placeholder="Invoice Date" required>
    <mat-icon matSuffix>date_range</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
```

and here is the form in which I'm storing my date. its `invoiceDate` variable.

```
this.newLoanForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      customerId: ['', Validators.required],
      orginizationId: ['', Validators.required],
      salesPersonId: ['', Validators.required],
      invoiceNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      invoiceDate: ['', Validators.required],
      notes: ['', Validators.required]
    })
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you tried using the date-ipe?

Comment: what is date-ipe ?

Answer (score 0):

Using moment.js makes your problem easy ,
Refer http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/ for more.

```
   1. npm install moment
    2. import * as _moment from 'moment';
    const moment = _moment;
    const utcDate = moment.utc();
    console.log(utcDate.format());
```

to parse the date u can refer the below code by using moment

```
const duration = moment.duration({ 'months': 0 });
if (this.variable33) {
  this.variable10 = moment(this.variable33).subtract(duration).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  console.log('date changed ', this.variable10);
```

Comment: I'm having a little confusion.
when I do `console.log(this.newLoanForm.value.invoiceDate);`
it gives me an object.
How do I now convert it to UTC. like you said above. 
is there any simple function, when I use like `myDate.toUTC()` and it gives me UTC format

Comment: can u send me the sample of date object

Comment: const isoDate = new Date('yourdatehere').toISOString();

Comment: this is the output when in console log my date